# Why a stream of the same image has different sizes in different versions of windows? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, image, system.drawing

I'm working on a project to merge image files into pdf documents. I have noticed that when I run the project on a server, the pdf's are bigger than on my development machine.

Debugging the code, I found out that when I load the image files into Image objects, I get different results.

I have this code:

```
        var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("PathToFile");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        var length = ms.ToArray().Length;
```

And (for example) an image file that is 589 kb

When I run that code over the image in a Windows 8 machine, lenght is 846781.
But when I run the same code over the same image in a Windows Server 2008 machine, lenght is 1232806.

Where does that difference come from? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is by any chance one of them 32bit and the other is 64bit?

Comment: Probably because different versions of GDI+ compress differently.

Comment: Different jpeg codec, most likely.

Comment: Both are 64 bits, I'll look into the GDI+ version and the codec stuff. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Try explicitly setting the quality parameter (say, to 95) and check the difference. The quality parameter has a huge effect on file size for JPEG images, and you are using a default here -- which may have changed.

Comment: Recompressing jpeg files is a bad idea.  Don't write code like that, use File.Copy().  Or post your real code, the dots-per-inch setting of the video adapter matters.